# Existence of local sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, rational-points

I would like to know when the property of "having a section" for a morphism of varieties in characteristic $0$ can be detected by spreading out to characteristic $p$.

Take a number field $K$, and let $R := \mathcal{O}_K[1/N]$ for some integer $N$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be projective flat $R$-schemes, and fix an $R$-map $f:X \to Y$. Assume that $f \otimes_R R/\mathfrak{m}$ has a section for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m} \subset R$. Does $f \otimes_R \overline{K}$ have a section for some algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$?

Note that taking the algebraic closure of $K$ is necessary (by the consideration of Brauer classes).

I suspect the answer is 'no' but cannot find a counterexample.

**Edit:** As Piotr's answer shows, the answer is 'yes' if one can bound the degrees of the sections of $f \otimes_R R/\mathfrak{m}$ independently of $\mathfrak{m}$. However, in practice, this could be hard to arrange, especially if the sections modulo $\mathfrak{m}$ are constructed using Frobenius (whose degree depends on $\mathfrak{m}$).

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes if you can bound the Hilbert polynomials of the graphs of the sections over different $\mathfrak{m}$. 
In such a situation, sections $Y\to X$ are points in finitely many components of the Hilbert scheme of $X\times Y$. Hence you have a scheme of finite type over $R$ (the scheme of sections with bounded Hilbert polynomial), which has non-empty fibers over all closed points of the base. It follows that the generic fiber is non-empty, hence has a $\bar K$-point.

Therefore in a hypothetical counterexample, the degrees of the sections over different $\mathfrak{m}$ have to go to infinity. Wouldn't that be weird?

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this case. However, it is not so weird to have degrees of the sections going off to $\infty$. For example, one might construct sections using Frobenius in some way, so the degree could grow like the residue characteristic. (In fact, this is how the question arose for me.)

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody else has mentioned this, let me point out the article of Bogomolov and Tschinkel.

MR2154371 (2006e:14024) Reviewed 
Bogomolov, Fedor(1-NY-X); Tschinkel, Yuri(D-GTN) 
Rational curves and points on K3 surfaces. (English summary) 
 
Amer. J. Math. 127 (2005), no. 4, 825–835. 
14G05 (11G35 14J28) 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0310254.pdf

Let $Z$ be a Kummer K3 surface with a specified very ample divisor class $D$, let $Y$ be $\mathbb{P}^1$ with one marked point $0$, and let $X$ be $Y\times Z$ with its obvious projection $\text{pr}_Y$ to $Y$, with the $Y$-ample divisor class $\text{pr}_Z^*D$, and with an arbitrary $K$-rational point $x_0$ in the fiber over $0$ marked.  Then Bogomolov and Tschinkel prove that for every finite field reduction $R/\mathfrak{m}$, there exists a section $s_{\mathfrak{m}}$ sending $0$ to $x_0$ and having positive degree with respect to $\text{pr}_Z^* D$, i.e., the section is not "horizontal".  They point out that **it may well be** that the same holds over $\overline{K}$, but nobody really knows this, and some people are skeptical.  So this is an example worth bearing in mind.